# R count values of a vector in ranges given by two other vectors

Tags: r, count, range

R:   Assume

```
length(v)=n length(a)=m=length(b), 
n and m are large;
v, a, b may contain NA or NaN's;  
a not necessarily smaller than b.
```

How to find the number of such pairs of indices i j that

```
a[j] < v[i] < b[j]
```

How to find the number of such (i,j) that either

```
a[j] < v[i] < b[j] or a[j] > v[i] > b[j]
```

This seems to be too slow:

```
sumrange <- function(v,ma)
{
  s <- 0
  for(i in 1:length(v))
  {
    s <- s + sum(v[i] > ma[,1] & ma[,2] > v[i], na.rm = TRUE)
  }
  s
}  
result <- sumrange(v, cbind(a, b))
```

EDIT: @DatamineR

```
a<-c(1,6,4,2,NA)
b<-c(5,4,0,7,0)
v<-c(3,5)
```

possible pairs in question 1:

```
1<3<5 (1,1)
2<3<7 (1,4)
2<5<7 (2,4)
```

result=3

possible pairs in question 2:  all the above and

6>5>4  (2,2)

result =3+1=4

EDIT:
Actually it works better is one first drops the NA's

```
vc<-na.omit(v)
ma<-na.omit(cbind(a,b))
result<-sumrange(vc,ma)
```

Comment: If you provided a simple example and a data set it would be much easier to help you

Comment: Also, expected output would help as it would help ensure that the loop you have is what you intended. In the loop you have, you are comparing 1 element of `v` to one entire column of `m`, is this what you intended to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this?

```
# some data:
set.seed(123)
a <- sample(1:15, 10)
b <- sample(1:15, 11)
c <- sample(1:15, 10)
a;b;c
 [1]  5 12  6 11 14  1 15  8  4  3
 [1] 15  7  9 14  2 13  3  1 10  6  5
 [1] 11  9 13  8 12  6 10  3  2 14


res <- sapply(b, function(x) apply(cbind(a,c), 1, function(y) (y[1] < x) & (x < y[2])))
which(res, arr.ind = TRUE)
      row col
 [1,]   1   2
 [2,]   3   2
 [3,]  10   2
 [4,]   1   3
 [5,]   3   3
 [6,]  10   3
 [7,]   6   5
 [8,]  10   6
 [9,]   6   7
[10,]   1   9
[11,]   3   9
[12,]  10   9
[13,]   1  10
[14,]  10  10
[15,]   6  11
[16,]  10  11
```

Here, the first column is the `j` and the second column is the `i`.

To include both conditions:

```
 res2 <- sapply(b, function(x) apply(cbind(a,c), 1, function(y) ((y[1] < x) & (x < y[2])) | ((y[1] > x) & (x > y[2])) ))
 which(res2, arr.ind = TRUE)
      row col
 [1,]   1   2
 [2,]   3   2
 [3,]   8   2
 [4,]  10   2
 [5,]   1   3
 [6,]   3   3
 [7,]   4   3
 [8,]  10   3
 [9,]   7   4
[10,]   6   5
[11,]   5   6
[12,]   7   6
[13,]  10   6
[14,]   6   7
[15,]   9   7
[16,]   1   9
[17,]   2   9
[18,]   3   9
[19,]   4   9
[20,]  10   9
[21,]   1  10
[22,]   8  10
[23,]  10  10
[24,]   6  11
[25,]   8  11
[26,]  10  11
```

Comment: Thank you, I ran your code and it does fine and gives all the information, but a bit too much of it as I wanted only the number of  the pairs (for now, next I may want to have the pairs themselves as well 8) The sapply/apply combo works however  slower than my primitive for loop. On a small sample with m=1000 and n=2000 and with data being dates: the for loop runs for  0.28 (using proc.time()) and the combo for 36.08. I am still looking for the speedup.

Answer (score 0):

I found a slightly faster way, using shingles 
It works best if one removes NA's beforehand

```
require(lattice)
vc<-na.omit(v)
ma<-na.omit(cbind(a,b))
sh<-shingle(vc,ma)
res<-sapply(levels(sh), function(x) sum(x[1] < vc & vc <= x[2]))  
result<-sum(res)
```

The timing on m=1000 (reduced to 912 by na.omit) and n=2000
is 0.12 as compared to 0.28 with the for loop (sumrange function) and 0.38 with the for loop without cleaning the data before applying it.

However I still do not know how to use the shingles if there are multiple criteria:  Say v is a n by 2 matrix and a and b are m by 2 matrices and we want to count  how many there are pairs (i,j)  such that

```
(a[j,1]<v[i,1]<b[j,1]) &  (a[j,2]<v[i,2]<b[j,2])
```

that is when   (multidimensional-) points lies in a (multidimensional-) rectangles